# Significance vs. goodness-of-fit in regression

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, p-value, goodness-of-fit

Assume that I am interested in analyzing the following linear regression model:
$$
Y  =  \beta_0 +\beta_1 x_1 +\beta_2 x_2+e 
$$

Please explain the difference between testing the p-value for each coefficient $\beta_i$ separately, and performing a **goodness-of-fit** test for the model?

In particular:

1. Is it true to say that the p-value for each coefficient corresponds to the null hypothesis that this coefficient is actually zero (for example, in MATLAB's `glmfit` function)?
2. Is it possible that a model resulting in a really good fit will have high p-values for all the coefficients? Is it possible that a model with low p-values for all the coefficients will result in a poor fit?

Answer (score 4):

1. *Yes*, the p-values that come with standard regression output are testing if the associated beta (slope coefficient) is $0$.  (It is possible to get p-values for tests against other values, but you have to know how to set that up—it isn't what software does by default, and it really isn't very common.)
2. *Yes*, you can have high p-values for individual coefficients with a good fit and low p-values with a poor fit.  The reason for this is straightforward: goodness of fit is a different question than whether the slope of the $X,\ Y$ relationship is $0$ in the population.  Generally, when running a regression, we are trying to determine a fitted line that traces [the conditional means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/71260/7290) of $Y$ at different values of $X$.  (It is also possible to wonder about other aspects of a model, but that is the most basic and common feature.)  Thus, a goodness of fit assessment is whether the model's fitted conditional means actually match the data's conditional means.  The answer to this latter question can be either *yes* or *no* independently of whether the best estimate of the slope is $0$.

   Consider the following examples, which are coded in R.  (I don't have access to MATLAB, but the code here is intended to be as close to pseudocode as I can make it.)

   ```r
   ##### high p-value, good fit
   set.seed(6462)                  # this makes the example exactly reproducible
   x1 = runif(100, min=-5, max=5)  # the x-variables are uniformly distributed
   x2 = runif(100, min=-5, max=5)  #  between -5 and 5
   e  = rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1)   # these are the errors
   y  = 0 + 0*x1 + 0*x2 + e        # the true intercept & sloes are 0

   m1 = lm(y~x1+x2)
   summary(m1)
   # ...
   # Coefficients:
   #               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
   # (Intercept) -0.1257881  0.0992355  -1.268    0.208     # these p-values are
   # x1           0.0009124  0.0307466   0.030    0.976     # high & non-significant
   # x2          -0.0243975  0.0316458  -0.771    0.443
   # 
   # Residual standard error: 0.9884 on 97 degrees of freedom
   # Multiple R-squared:  0.006149,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.01434 
   # F-statistic: 0.3001 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: 0.7415   # the whole model is ns
   ```

   [image]

   ```r
   ##### low p-values, poor fit
   # the true intercept & sloes are not 0, but the relationships are curvilinear
   y2 = 5 + 0.65*x1 + -0.17*x1^2 + 0.65*x2 + -0.17*x2^2 + e  

   m2 = lm(y2~x1+x2)
   summary(m2)
   # ...
   # Coefficients:
   #             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
   # (Intercept)  1.42633    0.21650   6.588 2.31e-09 ***  # very low p-values
   # x1           0.64189    0.06708   9.569 1.14e-15 ***
   # x2           0.58869    0.06904   8.527 2.01e-13 ***
   # ...
   # 
   # Residual standard error: 2.156 on 97 degrees of freedom
   # Multiple R-squared:  0.6152,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.6073 
   # F-statistic: 77.54 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
   ```

   [image]

   What these examples show are a model that has high / non-significant p-values, but a good fit for the predicted means (because the true slopes are $0$), and a model with very low / highly significant p-values, but a poor fit for the predicted means (because, although the slopes within the regions spanned by the data are far from $0$, they are also not very close to straight lines).  The p-values are easy to see and understand in the output.  To see the quality of the models' fits to the conditional means, I plotted the true data generating process (in this case I have it, because the data are simulated, but in general you won't).  In a more typical case, you would just see if the predicted means do a reasonable job of tracing the observed conditional means in your dataset; here I did that by plotting [LOWESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression) lines.  (The plots only display `x1`, and collapse over `x2`, but I could make analogous plots with `x2`, or various kinds of fancy plots with both `x1` and `x2`, and they would show the same thing.)

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer by @gung let's assume a simpler model of 
$$
Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 X + e 
$$
where we are estimating $Y$ using 
$$
\hat Y=\hat \beta_0 + \hat \beta_1 X.
$$
we have $n$ data points $x_i$ and $y_i$, $i=1,...,n$.

p-values for coefficients are calculated as:
$$
PV_i = Pr(t>t_i )
$$
where 
$$
t_i=\frac{|\hat \beta_i|}{SE(\beta_i)},
$$
$Pr$ is the probablity that $t$ (with t-distribution with $n-2$ degrees of freedom) is bigger than $t_i$ and $SE$ is standard error.

Larger $t_i$ leads to smaller p-value  and higher significance of the coefficients.

$$
SE(\beta_1)= \frac{\sigma_e}{\sqrt{n} \sigma_X}
$$
and thus
$$
t_1= \sqrt{n} \hat \beta_1  \frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_e}. \tag 1
$$
on the other hand adjusted R-squared is obtained as:
$$
R^2=1- \frac{1}{ \beta^2_1  \frac{\sigma^2_X}{\sigma^2_e} +1} \tag 2
$$

According to (1) p-values can be made arbitrarily small by increasing $n$. At the same time R-squared can be made smaller by decreasing signal to error ratio $\frac{\sigma^2_X}{\sigma^2_e}$, either owing to modelling error (neglecting important terms) or just random error. Hence you can have a bad fit and at the same time have low p-values for all of your coefficients.

The following combinations are possible:

1. Good fit-bad $R^2$-high or low p-value: This is possible if the model chosen correctly, but signal to error ratio $\frac{\sigma^2_X}{\sigma^2_e}$ is low. P-value $PV_1$ can be made arbitrarily large or small by changing $n$ if $\hat \beta_1 \neq 0$.
2. Bad fit-good $R^2$-high or low p-value: This is possible if model is chosen wrongly but  $\beta^2_1  \sigma^2_X$ is very large. Again P-value can be made arbitrarily large or small by changing $n$.
3. Obvious cases are bad fit-bad $R^2$ and good fit-good $R^2$.

To write this answer, I used the formulas listed in [this pdf](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/HumanitiesScience/StatLearning/asset/linear_regression.pdf).

Comment: This is a decent contribution. Note that $R^2$ does not measure goodness of fit (see famous rant by Cosma Shalizi starting on p. 17 of [this pdf](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/10/lecture-10.pdf)). I also don't understand the statement, "$Pr$ is t-distribution". You might mean 't-distribut*ed*', but even then, I don't follow it. $Pr(\cdot)$ is generally a probability. Under the null, $p$ should be uniform (& $t$ should have a central $t$-distribution).

Comment: Thanks for edits. I wrote the answer with haste and made a few errors. Regarding the shortcomings of $R^2$ I agree. But in the limited case of linear model with data following the same distribution I think we can use it, as also mentioned in the atricle.