# What is null hypothesis in the deviance goodness of fit test for a GLM model?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, goodness-of-fit, deviance

To test the goodness of fit of a GLM model, we use the Deviance goodness of fit test (to compare the model with the saturated model).

In many resource, they state that the null hypothesis is that "The model fits well" without saying anything more specifically (with mathematical formulation) what does it mean by "The model fits well".

Could you please tell me what is the mathematical form of the Null hypothesis in the Deviance goodness of fit test of a GLM model ?

Answer (score 2):

*The [other answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/530396/) is not correct.  The test of the model's deviance against the null deviance is not the test of the model against the saturated model.  It is the test of the model against the null model, which is quite a different thing (with a different null hypothesis, etc.).*

The test of the fitted model against a model with only an intercept is the test of the model as a whole.  This test is based on the difference between the model's deviance and the null deviance, with the degrees of freedom equal to the difference between the model's residual degrees of freedom and the null model's residual degrees of freedom (see my answer here: [Test GLM model using null and model deviances](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141179/7290)).  It is a test of whether the model contains any information about the response anywhere.  In general, when there is only one variable in the model, this test would be equivalent to the test of the included variable.  (For a GLM, there is an added complication that the types of tests used can differ, and thus yield slightly different p-values; see my answer here: [Why do my p-values differ between logistic regression output, chi-squared test, and the confidence interval for the OR?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/144608/7290))

The goodness of fit / lack of fit test for a fitted model is the test of the model against a model that has one fitted parameter for every data point (and thus always fits the data perfectly).  It is based on the difference between the saturated model's deviance and the model's residual deviance, with the degrees of freedom equal to the difference between the saturated model's residual degrees of freedom and the model's residual degrees of freedom.  For logistic regression models, the saturated model will always have $0$ residual deviance and $0$ residual degrees of freedom (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/414909/)).  Thus, you could skip fitting such a model and just test the model's residual deviance using the model's residual degrees of freedom.

**To answer this thread's explicit question: The null hypothesis of the lack of fit test is that the fitted model fits the data as well as the saturated model.  That is, there is no remaining information in the data, just noise.**  While we usually want to reject the null hypothesis, in this case, we want to fail to reject the null hypothesis.

To explore these ideas, let's use the data from my answer to [How to use boxplots to find the point where values are more likely to come from different conditions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/181501/7290)

```r
Cond.1 = c(2.9, 3.0, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.3, 3.3, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.5, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.7,
           3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.9, 4.0, 4.0, 4.1, 4.1, 4.2, 4.4, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.6,
           4.6, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 4.9, 5.5, 5.5, 5.7)
Cond.2 = c(2.3, 2.4, 2.6, 3.1, 3.7, 3.7, 3.8, 4.0, 4.2, 4.8, 4.9, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.7,
           5.8, 5.9, 5.9, 6.0, 6.0, 6.1, 6.1, 6.3, 6.5, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7.1, 7.1, 7.1,
           7.2, 7.2, 7.4, 7.5, 7.6, 7.6, 10, 10.1, 12.5)
dat    = stack(list(cond1=Cond.1, cond2=Cond.2))
```

For convenience, I will define two functions to conduct these two tests:

```r
lr.null.mod.test = function(model, digits=3){
  n.dev = model$null.deviance
  m.dev = model$deviance
  n.df  = model$df.null
  r.df  = model$df.residual
  ch.sq = n.dev - m.dev
  df    = n.df - r.df
  p     = 1-pchisq(ch.sq, df)
  out   = c(chi.sq=formatC(ch.sq, digits=digits-2, format="f"), 
            df=formatC(df, digits=0, format="d"), 
            p.value=formatC(p, digits=digits, format="f"))
  return(noquote(out))
}
lr.sat.mod.test = function(model, digits=3){
  m.dev = model$deviance
  n.df  = model$df.null
  r.df  = model$df.residual
  ch.sq = m.dev - 0
  df    = length(model$y) - length(model$coefficients)
  p     = 1-pchisq(ch.sq, df)
  out   = c(chi.sq=formatC(ch.sq, digits=digits-2, format="f"), 
            df=formatC(df, digits=0, format="d"), 
            p.value=formatC(p, digits=digits, format="f"))
  return(noquote(out))
}
```

Let's fit several models: 1) a null model with only an intercept; 2) our primary model using `x`; 3) a saturated model with a unique variable for every datapoint; and 4) a model also including a squared function of `x`.

```r
m.null = glm(ind~1,                  dat, family="binomial")
m.x    = glm(ind~values,             dat, family="binomial")
m.sat  = glm(ind~as.factor(1:78),    dat, family="binomial")
m.x.x2 = glm(ind~values+I(values^2), dat, family="binomial")
```

Now let's look at some abridged output for these models.

```r
summary(m.null)
# ...
#     Null deviance: 108.13  on 77  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 108.13  on 77  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 110.13
# ...
summary(m.sat)
# ...
# Deviance Residuals: 
#  [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
# [26]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
# [51]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
# [76]  0  0  0
# 
# Coefficients:
#                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept)       -2.657e+01  3.561e+05       0        1
# as.factor(1:78)2  -1.762e-14  5.036e+05       0        1
# ...
# as.factor(1:78)78  5.313e+01  5.036e+05       0        1
# 
# ...
#     Null deviance: 1.0813e+02  on 77  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 4.5252e-10  on  0  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 156
# 
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
summary(m.x)
# ...
# Deviance Residuals: 
#     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
# -1.5683  -0.7985  -0.2407   0.7207   2.3069  
# 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)  -4.9375     1.1616  -4.251 2.13e-05 ***
# values        1.0213     0.2412   4.235 2.28e-05 ***
# ...
#     Null deviance: 108.131  on 77  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance:  77.576  on 76  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 81.576
# ...
```

We see that the fitted model's reported null deviance equals the reported deviance from the null model, and that the saturated model's residual deviance is $0$ (up to rounding error arising from the fact that computers cannot carry out infinite precision arithmetic).  Let's conduct our tests as defined above, and nested model tests of the actual models.

```r
lr.null.mod.test(m.x)
#  chi.sq      df p.value 
#    30.6       1   0.000 
anova(m.null, m.x, test="LRT")
# Analysis of Deviance Table
# 
# Model 1: ind ~ 1
# Model 2: ind ~ values
#   Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
# 1        77    108.131                          
# 2        76     77.576  1   30.555 3.246e-08 ***
lr.sat.mod.test(m.x)
#  chi.sq      df p.value 
#    77.6      76   0.428 
anova(m.x, m.sat, test="LRT")
# Analysis of Deviance Table
# 
# Model 1: ind ~ values
# Model 2: ind ~ as.factor(1:78)
#   Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)
# 1        76     77.576                     
# 2         0      0.000 76   77.576   0.4282
```

We can see that the results are the same.  We also see that the lack of fit test was not significant.  Many people will interpret this as showing that the fitted model is correct and has extracted all the information in the data.  In fact, this is a dicey assumption, and is a problem with such tests.  It amounts to assuming that the null hypothesis has been *confirmed*.  As discussed in my answer to: [Why do statisticians say a non-significant result means “you can't reject the null” as opposed to accepting the null hypothesis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/85914/7290), this assumption is invalid.  We can see the problem, if we explore the last model fitted, and conduct its lack of fit test as well.  It fits better than our initial model, despite our initial model 'passed' its lack of fit test.  (In fact, one could almost argue that this model fits 'too well'; see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22350/7290).)

```r
summary(m.x.x2)
# ...
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)  18.0825     6.1130   2.958 0.003096 ** 
# values       -9.8912     2.9649  -3.336 0.000850 ***
# I(values^2)   1.2220     0.3449   3.543 0.000396 ***
# ...
# 
#     Null deviance: 108.131  on 77  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance:  56.884  on 75  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 62.884
# ...
anova(m.x, m.x.x2, test="LRT")
# Analysis of Deviance Table
# 
# Model 1: ind ~ values
# Model 2: ind ~ values + I(values^2)
#   Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
# 1        76     77.576                          
# 2        75     56.884  1   20.692 5.394e-06 ***
lr.sat.mod.test(m.x.x2)
#  chi.sq      df p.value 
#    56.9      75   0.941
```

Comment: +1 Spectacular answer!

Answer (score 0):

When we fit the saturated model we get the "Saturated deviance". When we fit another model we get its "Residual deviance". We can then consider the difference between these two values. If our model is an adequate fit, the residual deviance will be close to the saturated deviance right? Alternatively, if it is a poor fit, then the residual deviance will be much larger than the saturated deviance.

Our test is, $H_0$: The change in deviance comes from the associated $\chi^2(\Delta p)$ distribution, that is, the change in deviance is small because the model is adequate. $H_1$: The change in deviance is far too large to have come from that distribution, so the model is inadequate. There's a bit more to it, e.g. the next level of understanding would be why it should come from that distribution under the null, but I'll not delve into it now.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much! It is clearer for me now. Can i formulate the null hypothesis in this wording "H0: The change in the deviance is small, H1: The change in the deviance is large. And under H0 (change is small), the change SHOULD comes from the Chi-sq distribution). So if we can conclude that the change does not come from the Chi-sq, then we can reject H0. OR, it should be the other way around: BECAUSE the change in deviance ALWAYS comes from the Chi-sq, then we test whether it is small or big ? Thank you for the clarification! Your help is very appreciated for me.

Comment: Your first interpretation is correct. The change in deviance only comes from Chi-sq under H0, rather than ALWAYS coming from it. So we are indeed looking for evidence that the change in deviance did not come from chi-sq

Comment: -1, this is not correct.  The test of the model's deviance against the null deviance is not the test against the saturated model.  That is the test against the null model, which is quite a different thing (different null, etc.).

Comment: Thanks gung, small misremembering